# How do you target a button, which is in another component, with a method in App.vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm making a basic To Do app, where I have an input field and upon entering a task and pressing the "Enter" key the task appears in the list. Along with the task the `TodoCard.vue` component also generates a button, which I would like to use to delete the task.

I've added a `@click="removeTodo"` method to the button, but don't know where to place it, in the `TodoCard` component or in the `App.vue` file?

`TodoCard` component:

```
<template>
  <div id="todo">
    <h3>{{ todo.text }}</h3>
    <button @click="removeTodo(todo)">Delete</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['todo'],
  methods: {
    removeTodo: function (todo) {
  this.todos.splice(this.todos.indexOf(todo), 1)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input class="new-todo"
    placeholder="Enter a task and press enter."
    v-model="newTodo"
    @keyup.enter="addTodo">
    <TodoCard v-for="(todo, key) in todos" :todo="todo" :key="key" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TodoCard from './components/TodoCard'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      todos: [],
      newTodo: ''
    }
  },
  components: {
    TodoCard
  },
  methods: {
    addTodo: function () {
      // Store the input value in a variable
      let inputValue = this.newTodo && this.newTodo.trim()

      // Check to see if inputed value was entered
      if (!inputValue) {
        return
      }

      // Add the new task to the todos array
      this.todos.push(
        {
          text: inputValue,
          done: false
        }
      )

      // Set input field to empty
      this.newTodo = ''
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Also is the code for deleting a task even correct?

Comment: Allow the parent to pass an `@click` handler to `TodoCard`. Then in the parent, splice `todos`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send an event to your parent notifying the parent that the delete button is clicked in your child component.

You can check more of this in Vue's [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Sending-Messages-to-Parents-with-Events).

And here's how your components should look like:

`TodoCard.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div id="todo">
    <h3>{{ todo.text }}</h3>
    <button @click="removeTodo">Delete</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['todo'],
  methods: {
    removeTodo: function (todo) {
       this.$emit('remove')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input class="new-todo"
    placeholder="Enter a task and press enter."
    v-model="newTodo"
    @keyup.enter="addTodo">
    <TodoCard v-for="(todo, key) in todos" :todo="todo" :key="key" @remove="removeTodo(key)" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TodoCard from './components/TodoCard'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      todos: [],
      newTodo: ''
    }
  },
  components: {
    TodoCard
  },
  methods: {
    addTodo: function () {
      // Store the input value in a variable
      let inputValue = this.newTodo && this.newTodo.trim()

      // Check to see if inputed value was entered
      if (!inputValue) {
        return
      }

      // Add the new task to the todos array
      this.todos.push(
        {
          text: inputValue,
          done: false
        }
      )

      // Set input field to empty
      this.newTodo = ''
        }
      },
     removeTodo: function(key) {

       this.todos.splice(key, 1);

     }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I am getting an undefined error from ESlint saying `key` isn't defined in `this.todos.splice(key, 1)`?